# Subquery takes 67 seconds to process, using temp table is instantaneous

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Running the following a query of the following form takes over 60 seconds to process.

```
SELECT *
FROM View_A
WHERE ( Column_1 IN (SELECT Column_1 FROM View_B WHERE Column_2 = 'my_test_value' OR Column_3 = 'my_test_value'))
```

Using a Temp Table the batch returns the same result in less than 1 second.

```
SELECT Column_1
INTO #temp1
FROM View_B
WHERE Column_2 = 'my_test_value' OR Column_3 = 'my_test_value'

SELECT *
FROM View_A
WHERE  Column_1 IN (SELECT * FROM #temp1)
```

Running the original query with either of the tests removed (no OR) results in a sub-second result. Also running the sub-query `(SELECT Column_1 FROM View_B WHERE Column_2 = 'my_test_value' OR Column_3 = 'my_test_value')` without the surrounding query is also sub-second in response.

I tried using `UNION ALL` but in some cases both column 2 and column 3 have the same value due to the architecture of the legacy application. As a result `union all` gives me duplicate rows. And some of the columns in view A are `text` so a straight `union` complains that it can not compare the column values.

Columns 1,2 & 3 are all indexed and the relationships between tables referenced in Views A & B are based on foreign key constraints.

Any insight on where to look next would be greatly appreciated. I need to get a concise SQL Query that performs like the temp table solution.

Comment: Isn't the temp table solution "like the temp table solution"? Is there any particular reason you can't just use that?

Comment: Can you provide the execution plans for all three queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `UNION` - `OR` is notorious for performing badly in certain queries.

As you have indicated that a `text` column is preventing the `union` from working, instead of using `*` (which is never best practice anyway), list your columns and convert any `text` columns to `varchar(max)`.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, convert(varchar(max),TextCol1) -- And so on
FROM View_A
WHERE (Column_1 IN (SELECT Column_1 FROM View_B WHERE Column_2 = 'my_test_value'))
union
SELECT Col1, Col2, convert(varchar(max),TextCol1) -- And so on
FROM View_A
WHERE (Column_1 IN (SELECT Column_1 FROM View_B WHERE Column_3 = 'my_test_value'));
```

As you have indicated that a `union` does improve the performance (to 9s), but that its still not fast enough, try a window function i.e. where you assign each row a row number based on whether it is unique or not (as I don't know your schema I don't know what that is, so you need to replace the `ColUnique` with the actual unique condition.

So the steps are:

1. Obtain the data as fast as possible, now using a `UNION ALL`
2. Add an outer query with a row number based on whatever makes a row unique
3. Filter out any duplicate rows using a second outer query

```
    select ColUnique, Col1, Col2, Col3
    from (
      select ColUnique, Col1, Col2, Col3
        , row_number() over (partition by ColUnique order by ColUnique) row#
      from (
        SELECT ColUnique, Col1, Col2, Col3 -- and so on
        FROM View_A
        WHERE (Column_1 IN (SELECT Column_1 FROM View_B WHERE Column_2 = 'my_test_value'))
        union all
        SELECT ColUnique, Col1, Col2, Col3
        FROM View_A
        WHERE (Column_1 IN (SELECT Column_1 FROM View_B WHERE Column_3 = 'my_test_value')) 
      ) X
    ) Y
    where Y.row# = 1;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try union. In some cases both column 2 and column 3 have the same value due to the architecture of the legacy application. As a result union all gives me duplicate rows. And some of the columns in view a are text so a straight union complains that it can not compare the column values.

Comment: Yes, running a union all results in acceptable query performance.

Comment: @BitLagoon use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

Comment: The columns to be returned contain non-comparable data types. Specifically data type "text"

Comment: Just convert your `text` columns to `varchar(max)`

Comment: SELECT * FROM sol_abs_0_query WHERE ( idnk08_k08 IN (SELECT idnk08_k08 FROM dbo.mcr_test_1_view WHERE prtnum_k15 LIKE 'ag3446631302'))
 UNION
 SELECT *  FROM sol_abs_0_query WHERE ( idnk08_k08 IN (SELECT idnk08_k08 FROM dbo.mcr_test_1_view WHERE partno_k08 LIKE 'ag3446631302'))

Msg 5335, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data type text cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

Comment: @BitLagoon With the query in this answer, that is impossible. If you're `select *`ing the same table on both sides of the `UNION` then you couldn't possibly have mismatched data types. As far as I know, `UNION` won't throw an error anywhere that `UNION ALL` doesn't.

Comment: @mypetlion - OP is correct, `TEXT` datatype fails in a straight `UNION` but converting to `VARCHAR(MAX)` resolves it.

Comment: Is it possible to cast the text column to varchar during the query or do I need to request a table modification from the owner?

Comment: Cast it in the query, but you have to list all the columns (which you should do anyway).

Comment: Removing the two "text" columns and re-running the query with union the result takes 9 seconds. I'd love to dig a little deeper.

Comment: Yeah, `union` doesn't perform nearly as well as `union all`. Next step is a window. Hang on.

Comment: OK, try the window function I have added - you will have to work out the row_number because I don't know your schema (check the reference docs if in doubt).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out now. In this case Column_1 is our unique row identifier.